# Python 2.7/3 C module for working with unicode strings

Tags: python, c, unicode

I've got stuck with different approaches about UTF-8/16 in Python modules. It was my first attempt to write Python C module at all, and I want to find out, how to get  all bytes from Unicode object to process these with C functions. As I see, these may be represented as simple ASCII string in C char array?

```
static PyObject* unicode_worker(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
Py_UNICODE  *src;
int srclen;
register Py_UNICODE ch;
wchar_t widecharBuffer[4096];

if (! PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "u#", &src, &srclen))
    return NULL;

ch = *src;

PyUnicode_AsWideChar((PyUnicodeObject *)src, widecharBuffer, srclen-1);

Py_RETURN_NONE;
}
```

Now when I use gdb like:

```
gdb python
run sh.py
```

I can see error:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000036010b05c8 in PyUnicodeUCS4_AsWideChar () from /usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

What could be improved in PyUnicode_AsWideChar call and what is wrong now?

**UPD**: Mats Petersson, the problem now is more clear.

Comment: Have you tried it? Exactly what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found, that I didn't paid my attention one important thing: Py_UNICODE contains all the text-data I needed and that's all. Size of this type in bytes may vary, so in different operating systems that should be checked. Anyway, I have no difference between wchar_t and Py_UNICODE in my Linux build, so the only next problem I faced was setting the locale. It was solver simply:

```
if (! setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.utf8")) return PyErr_SetFromErrno(SetLocaleError);
wprintf(L"%ls\n", src);
```

Now I can continue experimenting with python modules, this problem seems to be solved.